# How to create a scrollable heatmap with plotly?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I wonder whether it is possible to create a heatmap with scrollbars in plotly/dash? Sometimes I have data with thousands of rows or columns and I would like to visualize it in a heatmap, but not all at once. So, it would be nice to select maybe 10/20 rows/columns at a time and have a scrollbar. Has anyone done that before?

Comment: A quick look through Plotly's [docs for the heatmap](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#heatmap) didn't show any way to specify scrolling in any direction, so I'm tempted to say "no".

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the heatmap into a scrollable `html.Div` using the `overflow` CSS property:

`style=dict(height='500px',overflow='scroll')`

This will give you a div limited to a given height and that has the ability to scroll down. Use the `overflowY` CSS property if you only want to scroll down.